# select files on local disk from a webapp

Tags: javascript, jquery

i should need to select from a webapp a list of local files (or a directory)
and pass only the path of selected files or directory to a POST end
(via json or via parameter)

webkitdirectory is not suitable, doesn't work on firefox as not standard,
and i don't need the multipart

thinking if jquery-file-upload could accomplish the task
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

any suggestion?

Comment: "For security reasons browsers do no allow this" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav

Comment: You need to select automatically or manually?